# Add a custom field to top attribute in WooCommerce

Tags: metabox, woocommerce-offtopic

i kinda went crazy trying to solve this.

I need to add a **custom select field** (and save it) to WooCommerce Attributes edit / insert new page - in each top level attribute - not the sub "terms"...

See picture
[image]

I tried writing a meta box for taxonomies but i guess these are not taxonomies and are saved differently in the database.

Need help to understand / find a solution

Comment: Did you manage to solve this case? I'm looking for the same solution

Comment: Sorry, its a while back - i cant remember what i did in the end. I think (not sure) that i used a custom function in conjuction with the ACF plugin. Sorry i couldnt help more.

Comment: this question needs an answer, maybe a blog post too. If you can, please share the solution you found.

Comment: it was too long ago. i am sure i solved it but i guess i forgot to come back and share it - gona search for it